Is unintentional jhana possible or even common?
I have a friend who is a Christian. It is a truism that most people can't tolerate sitting and doing nothing because of catastrophic dukkha.
Most people, including people I know, have to DO something all the time. But my old friend would spend hours sitting on his porch, a smile on his face, by himself, just enjoying the present moment. Is this a form of jhana? Is it possible that there are many run of the mill, non-buddhist people who actually understand and practice a kind of jhana unintentionally?

Many people may not what jhana is or what Buddha taught but they could be very wise. It is the layman task which may lead to a concentrated mind. They may not have any intention to enter any absorption of jhana but the job which they took to earn their bread might generate joy and happiness. If they believe in God , Allah or Vishnu etc they might enter into the realm of pure happiness. There is no intention to enter any jhana but it happens automatically.
Buddha taught something beyond jhana(end of suffering ).His foremost style is to get rid of self views. The purpose is not be happy or joyful or to focus on present moment but to get rid of self view. Whatever phenomena which may arise is ultimately not me , mine or myself.
This style of meditation definitely requires proper attention and intention.
This is what separates Buddha’s model of jhana from other official or unofficial religions(like cooking , making money etc)

MN 14 lists some indicators of jhana:

When I had attained a rapture & pleasure apart from sensuality, apart from
unskillful mental qualities, or something more peaceful than that,
that was when I claimed that I could not be tempted by sensuality.
Now, I — without moving my body, without uttering a word — can dwell
sensitive to unalloyed pleasure for a day and a night... for two days
& nights... for three... four... five... six... seven days & nights.
MN 14


That is an indicator of the Blessed One's perfecting it. Is jahna only attained by non-returners, those who "could not be tempted by sensuality"?

Yes. Refer to AN 3.86
